# What is the most powerful way to import data into a Neo4J database?

Tags: neo4j

I have 150 Mysql tables of about 3M rows with just over 200 columns per row at the moment (the number will only increase),
I would like to transfer my tables to a single Neo4J database with each field being a node,
so with the numbers above it would be :

- 150 => number of tables
- 3M => number of rows
- 200 => number of fields
- 10 => number of possible values in each field on average

so (150 * 3000000) + (200 * 10)= 450'002'000 nodes approximately

Which method will be the most appropriate for importing so many nodes and relationships?
knowing that there are 6 specific nodes that serve as unique identifiers and that must therefore be merged to avoid duplicates.

I think the MATCH is extremely heavy so I guess it should be avoided as much as possible, do you think it will be useful to use a method to know if the node exists other than asking Neo4J (for example a MongoDB) in order to avoid a MATCH, is a good idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

in most scenarios for importing data, you use `MERGE` instead of `MATCH` which allows you to create and re-use unique entities. Make sure you have your CONSTRAINTS setup correctly before you start the import. [This](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/load-csv/) is a good place to start reading.

Comment: I confirm this link is very good, testing the import by CSV of node and relation is very fast but I would like to know if there are tips to generate the csv file, avoid merge etc...

Comment: you definitely don't want to avoid MERGE :)  . but you can also read this: https://neo4j.com/developer/relational-to-graph-import/

Answer (score 1):

with the number of rows you will be importing you might consider [apoc.periodic.iterate](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/). It batches the loading and has retries if there is short duration locking. Also, consider the garbage that can accumulate (in gB quantities) in the transaction logs. I add a few lines in the config file to keep it cleaned up:

```
dbms.checkpoint.interval.time=30s
dbms.checkpoint.interval.tx=1
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=false
dbms.tx_log.rotation.size=1M
dbms.transaction.timeout=30m
```

As Graphileon mentions, make sure you have nodes and relationships indexed in advance of the load; otherwise you'll have very long load times. Also, keep in mind that any change in properties will create duplicates even with MERGE.